Controlling duplicate api calls with milli/micro seconds delay (concurrency)
I have a POST API, where you can save some data for a customer, there is a possibility that somebody can programatically initiates multiple calls with same data in milli/micro seconds time.
Now As i accepeted the first request and processing which includes validations (db reads) and then finally saves (db insert with transaction). But if the insert takes a little bit of time to finish, the other requests pass validation for duplicate entries(db reads) and then once the first request finishes 2nd request waits at the insert as first gets lock and then both times data gets inserted.
can't just simply add restriction on table for unique data (consider a denormalized db design) and the db reads are not happening with read uncommited and involves multiple tables
I feel like creating a unique key for a customer when the requests comes in and delete the key after request process finishes, untill then customer cannot access that resource, but it may have some drawbacks.
Looking for some solutions how can these situations be handled(imagine a case for 100s of apis, i cannot simply write all validations in db inserts transaction to rollback).

Sounds like you want to use sp_getapplock, the magic sauce of denormalized database design

are you using entity framework?

Seems a system design flaw if you can get a bunch of duplicate requests? But even then your insert can have a not exists condition to prevent all but the first record from being inserted.

sounds like you have have an XY problem due to a design flaw.

To achieve your requirement you could add a rowversion or timestamp column to your table. When a client sends an API request, it includes a unique key. The server checks if this key has been processed by querying a database table. If the key exists, the server returns the stored response. If not, the server processes the request as new.

During processing, the server uses optimistic concurrency control with SQL Server, checking the rowversion or timestamp before updating the record. If it matches, the server updates the record, commits the transaction, and stores the idempotency key and result. If it doesn't match, the transaction is rolled back, and an error is returned. The server saves the key and response data, ensuring future requests with the same key can quickly return the stored response. The client then receives the processed response.

Don't you have a natural customer unique key in the data set. If, yes then  create a unique key against it and then db handle the duplicate. You just handle the duplicate exception coming from db in your api code. In case you don't have a unique key identifier then consider all the fields as a composite key and create a unique index in db and follow the same process. In any case, my suggestion is to let db handle the duplicates. I am assuming the db which you are considering has inbuilt concurrency control mechanism. Hope this helps.
